# Modifying workflow to assign task to group instead of user

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have created a 2010 workflow in SPD where I am assigning task to group and the option "Expand group" (or something like that) is enabled which means task is assigned to user who is part of that group.

Now I want to change this behaviour i.e. I want to assign task to group instead of user inside it.

If I make this change, it will only take effect for new instance of worklow but existing workflows won't be updated which is what I don't want. Is there a way to make this change for existing workflows also?

Comment: are you tried to use 'Assign a custom form to these users' action then select group? it's available for WF 2010.

Comment: Is this option available in SPD?

Comment: Yes, in Action List, Below Task Actions.